# jQuery plugin not working inside PHP While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code which shows facebook type reactions. The problem is that its not working inside PHP while loop. Do I need to add a unique identifier or something? If yes, how? Any help would be appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php while($a = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
  <div class="feed">
    <a class="like-btn">
      <div class="reaction-box">
        <div class="reaction-icon like">
          <label>Like</label>
        </div>
        <div class="reaction-icon love">
          <label>Love</label>
        </div>
        <div class="reaction-icon haha">
          <label>Hot</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

jQuery

```
$(".like-btn").hover(function() {
  $(".reaction-box").fadeIn(100, function() {
    $(".reaction-icon").each(function(i, e) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(e).addClass("showed");
      }, i * 100);
    });
  });
}, function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".reaction-box").fadeOut(300, function(){
      $(".reaction-icon").removeClass("showed")
    })
  }, 500);
});
```

I didn't put CSS here because I guess its not required. If required please comment below and I will update the question. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what "isn't working"? what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Is reaction-box be hidden at the beginning? Otherwise fadeIn callback is never called

Comment: Yes, its hidden in the beginning

Comment: Not working means the reaction box isn't coming up or shown. It works well outside while loop.

Comment: Are you creating all the buttons dynamically at runtime, or is the loop done when the page is first loaded?

Comment: Its like the posts are coming from Infinite Scrolling (like facebook)... The more you scroll down the new content will keep on loading... you can say its getting fetched again and again via AJAX...and every post contains this button for reactions just like facebook...

Comment: perhaps the loop isn't running because of the `while` condition

Comment: while condition is itself a loop right? that's why we call it a while loop.. the records are being fetched well... the problem is that when this button is added it doesn't work.. the reactions box doesn't pop up.. but its working well when HTML part is placed outside of while loop..

Comment: is all this content being added to the DOM after the page is already loaded?

Comment: I am not using pure javascript for DOM.. I am using jquery and you can see that.